# Show dynamic li with jquery mobile style in Ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile

I am having left side ul and right side ul. When i am clicking left side li making an ajax call in that ajax call i am adding a dynamic li in right side ul. The content was coming but the jquery mobile design was missing. I searched i got a solution like add `$("#ul_id").listview('refresh')` but it's not working for me.

```
$.post('/app/Unit/unit_detail', {item_id : task_id},
  function(data){
    $('#right_ul').html(data);
    $("#right_ul").listview('refresh');
});
```

In my unit_detail.erb i am having the following code

```
<li class="showDetails" style="list-style:none;" data-theme="b">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
      <div class="ui-block-a"><div><%= unit_detail.name %></div></div>
      <div class="ui-block-b"><div><%= unit_detail.description %> </div></div>
      <div class="ui-block-c"><div><%= unit_detail.accessories %> </div></div>
    </div> 
  </a>
</li>
```

In some place i found first find the id of ul in div and refresh the list view

```
$("#rigth_pane_content_footer").find("#right_ul").listview('refresh');
```

I tried that also not working.

In my page i am having the following

```
<div id="rigth_pane_content_footer">
  <ul data-role="listview" id="right_ul">     
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.post('/app/Unit/unit_detail', {item_id : task_id},
 function(data){
   var container = document.getElementById('right_ul');
   var new_element = document.createElement('li');
   new_element.innerHTML =data;
   container.appendChild(new_element);
   $(container).listview("refresh"); 
 });
```

Comment: Working as same (without jquery mobile style)

Comment: I wrote it as container only. li coming without jquery mobile style. That doesn't use data-theme="b", class="ui-grid-b" as i mentioned in the unit_detail.erb